# Grep for only binary (0,1) numbers in a file with base 10 numbers

Tags: grep, regular-expression, binary

So let's say i have a file with both binary numbers (0,1) and some other numbers in base 10 (0-9):

```
010... 10567
011... 23678
...
```

etc.

the above example isn't actually their exact representation but that's beside the point (and only to illustrate this specific case)

I already know how to grep for only "numbers" in a file/output:

```
grep '[0-9]*'
```

Using this:

```
grep '[0-1]*'
```

Would highlight/select the 1 and 0 that are part of the base10 numbers.

So I'm unsure how to do the same thing for *just* binary numbers (0,1).
So that the example output would only show the binary numbers (binaries are always in the same column).

Any ways to do this?

Comment: The problem is that for example, 10 is a binary as well a base 10 number. Do you have another criteria in your file that can help distinguish them?

Comment: well, i guess there always a space between the binary(1,0) and the base10/decimal numbers in the example output...would that help? :) @schrodigerscatcuriosity

Comment: Are the binaries always in the same column then?

Comment: yep :) they are. @schrodigerscatcuriosity

Comment: Then you don't need `grep` unless you want specific binaries. Let's say they are in the first column, so you use `awk`: `awk '{ print $1 }' file`.

Comment: oh yeah! didn't thought of doing this even though i know awk a bit... @schrodigerscatcuriosity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following would look at the data in column `col`, and whenever the data in that column consists of only ones and zeros, that data is printed.

The `col` column number is given on the command line (I'm using `1` as its value here):

```
awk -v col=1 '$col ~ /^[01]+$/ { print $col }' file
```

If you know that your binary numbers always start with a zero, then you may change the expression from `^[01]+$` to `^0[01]*$` (a zero followed by any number of ones and/or zeros).  If you *additionally* know that your binary numbers are always three digits long, use `^0[01][01]$` or `^0[01]{2}$`.

Testing:

```
$ cat file
010 10567
011 23678
030 10567
012 23678
```

```
$ awk -v col=1 '$col ~ /^[01]+$/ { print $col }' file
010
011
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution is:

```
grep -E "\<[01]+\>" filename
```

`\<` and `\>` are word boundaries and the regular expression matches 1 or more occurrences of `01`.

You may also use awk to match in just the specified column; using awk, if the binary string is in column 1, you can do the following:

```
awk 'match($1,/\<[01]+\>/) {print $1}'
```

Comment: That would erroneously identify decimal numbers consisting only of a leading one and zero or more ones and zeros (for example `10`)

Comment: That way, any binary number can be considered a decimal as well.  And I suggested to restrict to a column, if necessary.

Comment: Perhaps you could demonstrate how to "_use `awk` to match_"

Answer (score 0):

As i found out a better solution (credit to @Inian in the comment section of [the earlier post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/629010/409852) for the solution)

```
grep -E '\b[01]+\b'
```

which seems to work on actual binary-only input. It does not falsely match binary numbers that are part of a decimal/other numbers too.

So:

```
echo "10198865" |  grep -E '\b[01]+\b'
```

output nothing, but:

```
echo "101010" |  grep -E '\b[01]+\b'
```

does.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to search for some number of consecutive `0` and `1` that don't have any other digits directly before or after. So, something like this, for at least 3 consecutive `0` and `1` (untested):

```
[^2-9][01]{3,}[^2-9]
```

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, this also matches something like '210001'.

Comment: works by using `grep -E yourregex` :D! (could be added to your answer for more clarity imo)

Comment: Or get [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep). It's much better than grep and has a modern regex engine (the one in grep is from the stone age).

Comment: this seems to work even better :o @Inian Thanks!

Comment: This would identify `a011b` as a binary number. It also does not restrict the match to a single column.

Comment: That would erroneously identify decimal numbers consisting only of a leading one and zero or more ones and zeros (for example `10000`)

Comment: That also matches on the `10001` in `3100014` for instance

Comment: @NordineLotfi Please move the accept to one of the better solutions :)